# Why change on pressure affects the boiling point much more than the freezing point?

Tags: boiling-point, gas-phase-chemistry

I do see the mathematical solution given by the classius clapyeron equation but is there any real life and intuitive expalanation?

Comment: Because there's much greater difference in volume.

Comment: Don't make it complicated. Gases are very compressible, fluids are not.

Comment: Forget compressible. Gases are _big_; liquids and solids are not.